# Syntax error on trigger driving me mad

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

Please hel pme to find the error i m losing my mind in this stupid thing....

```
CREATE TRIGGER ControlVoto
BEFORE INSERT ON havotato
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (NEW.voto<0)
then insert into Errori(id_errore) values(1)
end IF;
end
```

Comment: what is the error? try :new.voto instead...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were missing an `;` and use need to set a delimiter in MySQL which I assume you are using

```
delimiter |
CREATE TRIGGER ControlVoto BEFORE INSERT ON havotato
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
   IF (NEW.voto < 0) then 
      insert into Errori(id_errore) values(1);
   end IF;
end
|
delimiter ;
```

If you don't set another delimiter than `;`, then the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You need to tell *MySQL* that the statement should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

Comment: why in this query i didn t need a delimiter?                      CREATE TRIGGER ControlDataEp
BEFORE INSERT ON Episodi
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.data_trasmissione = 
(
  SELECT IF(IFNULL(MAX(data_trasmissione), 0) < NEW.data_trasmissione, NEW.data_trasmissione, NULL)
    FROM Episodi 
   WHERE titolo_episodio = NEW.titolo_episodio
     AND numero = NEW.numero - 1
);

Comment: Because that trigger does not contain any `;` in the definition.

Comment: If you don't set another delimiter than `;` the statement will end at the first `;` and your trigger definition will be incomplete. You  need to tell MySQL that the stamentment should end at the delimiter you defined. After that you can set the delimiter back with `delimiter ;`

Answer (score 0):

You have to use :NEW in your expression

```
CREATE TRIGGER ControlVoto
BEFORE INSERT ON havotato
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
IF (:NEW.voto<0)
then insert into Errori(id_errore) values(1)
end IF;
end
```